# Lithium PHP framework - How to run db transaction on mysql?

Tags: php, lithium

I have been working on an e-commerce website in PHP Lithium framework, actually this one is upgraded from CakePHP, we have to use transaction operation on db in mysql. Just don't know how to do db transaction in PHP Lithium framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Lithium uses PDO, you can just get the PDO object and call the beginTransaction() method.

```
$foo = app\models\Foo::create();
$pdo = Connections::get('default')->connection; 
$pdo->beginTransaction();
$foo->bar = 'Hello';
$foo->save();
$pdo->commit();
```

https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/issues/1004#issuecomment-23690165
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php

Comment: Thanks. I saw your comment in issues page.

Comment: Brilliant! +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like it is supported, unfortunately. See source of [lithium/data/source/database/adapter/MySql.php](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/master/data/source/database/adapter/MySql.php#L130).

An alternative may be to manually execute your queries.

Within your model, you can do:

```
static::connection->read($sql, $placeholders);
```

Where `$sql` is your raw SQL like:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = {:id}';
```

and `$placeholders` (optional) are your placeholders:

```
$placeholders = [
    'id' => 5
];
```

Using that knowledge, you should be able to set up a transaction.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to make it possible.